# Can repr in a Python class automatically return the format 'ClassName(prop=val...)'?

Tags: python, oop, built-in, repr

Here is a small class:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
    self.b = 2
```

I make an object:

```
a = Foo()
```

Which has `repr`:

```
In [6]: repr(a)
Out[6]: '<__main__.Foo object at 0x10e228f28>'
```

I would like it to be

```
Foo(a=1, b=2)
```

Since I think this is a standard format (according to what standard though?). Besides manually writing out this format for each class I make, I would expect there be a standard way to program a class so that its `__repr__` method simply codes off of its data, or some set of parameters I tell it. What is Pythonic here?

Comment: There is nice package for this 
https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs

Comment: As far as I understand, that "standard" format is still hardcoded. If that was standard, you'd have some pretty long reprs sometimes.

Comment: *"according to what standard though?"* - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: @Thundzz yeah, but it's 8 years old (pre 3 I think) and the answers are pretty terrible. This one at least is plausibly pythonic https://stackoverflow.com/a/38540861/1339987